# TestNG not ordering classes as specified in the testng.xml file

Tags: selenium, testng

My testng.xml file looks like:

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="testng.Test1"/>

      <methods>
        <include name="Browse()"></include>
        <include name="Login()"></include>
        <include name="Reg()"></include>                      
      </methods>

      <class name="testng.Test2"></class>

    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
```

The output of Test1 is:

```
*Login 
Register 
Browse*
```

The output of Test2 is

```
2
```

But, when i run the testng.xml file, the output looks like:

```
*Login Register 2 Browse*.
```

So, before the Test1 is completed, it is picking the Test2 and printing the output.

How can we run it, so that Test1 is executed first completely, followed by Test2?

I tried using preserve-order="true" but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've taken the liberty of clarifying your question title and of adjusting the formatting of your post to make it easier to read and more likely to attract the attention of someone who may know the answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you are asking for here but according to your xml file, you should include your `methods` in your `class` before closing it.

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
<test name="Test">
    <classes>
        <class name="testng.Test1">
            <methods>
                <include name="Browse()"></include>
                <include name="Login()"></include>
                <include name="Reg()"></include>
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class name="testng.Test2"/>
    </classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
```

This way all the methods in your "Test1" will run first and then rest of the tests will run.

Learn more [here](http://testng.org/doc/selenium.html#creating_xml).